# std::function check inheritance of classes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, std-function

How to enclose `std::is_base_of` in a `std::function` practically?

I don't think it is possible, because the type is erased.

How to workaround?    I want to cache `std::function f=check whether X derived from B`.
 It will be called later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
class B{ };
class C: B{};
int main(){
    std::cout<<std::is_base_of<B,C>()<<std::endl; //print 1
    std::function<bool()> f=[](X)->bool{  //<--- syntax error (X is class name)
        return std::is_base_of<B,X>();
    };
    std::cout<<f(C)<<std::endl;   //<--- possible? (should print 1)
    return 0;
}
```

In real case, `f` is called in a far-away location of code, and I don't want to instantiate `B` or `C`.
(Thus, I can't use `dynamic_cast` to check.)

### **(Edit) Underlying Problem :-**

I am trying to get a 2D-bool table (`result #`) for some sophisticated types manipulation.

```
class B{};
class C : B{};
class D{};
int main(){

    for(auto cachefunction : cacheFunctions){
        cachefunction();
        //^ "cacheFunctions" is {register<B>(), register<C>(), register<D>()}
    }
    //in real case, cacheFunctions.size() ~ 200+
    auto result=.... //#
}
```

I **can** edit code inside `register<T>()` to whatever I want, but I **can't** request user to call `register<T1,T2>` for every possible tuple.

Roughly speaking, the `result #` is an array of `bool` flag whether `T2` derived from `T1`.

```
       B  C  D  (parent)
   ------------
(derived)
   B   x  0  0
   C   1  x  0
   D   0  0  x    (x=don't care, 0 or 1 are OK)
```

`int[]/std::vector<int> result` = `{x,0,0 , 1,x,0 , 0,0,x}`.

My ultimate goal is to get the table at the line `//#`.

### **(Edit) Underlying Problem 2nd attempt :-**

I have a user code that calls my library like this.
These lines are scattering around many user's `.cpp` :-

```
requestSystem<S1>()->someBFunction();
requestSystem<S2>()->someCFunction();
....
```

`Si` are sub-systems in my library (Here, I use composition rather that inheritance.).

So far, I have successfully used some trick (`array of std::function`) to instantiate  those sub-system (`new Si()`), before those functions are actually called at run-time.   Thus, it runs fine.

As my program grow, more `Si` are born.
 I notice that there are appropriate cases where some `Sy` are best to inherit from a certain `Sx`.

[image]

In such cases, I find that if I instantiate both `new Sx()` and `new Sy()`, my program will act strangely, because there are two instance of base class `Sx` (it should be singleton by design).

I think it would be nice if I can detect such cases automatically by embedding some additional code inside `requestSystem<T>()` to instantiate only `new S_Y()`, and let `requestSystem<S_X>()` return the same pointer to `S_Y`.

I can't use the same trick (`array of std::function`) for `std::is_base_of` to check inheritance because the type is erased.      Moreover, I intend to not call `new S_X()`, so I can't cache the type by its instance and use `dynamic_cast` later.

Here is MCVE ([ideone](http://ideone.com/4Awzdp)).
The first part is Manager's definition:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
class Manager{
    public: Manager(){std::cout<<"Manager"<<std::endl; }
};
class EntityManager : public Manager{
    public: EntityManager(){std::cout<<"EntityManager"<<std::endl;}
};
class AdvanceEntityManager : public EntityManager{
    public: int testField=5; //just for testing
    public: AdvanceEntityManager(){
        std::cout<<"AdvanceEntityManager"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

Here is the type-manipulator :-

```
template<class T> class DummyHook{ public: static int dummyInt;  };
template<class T> class IndexCache{ public: static int index; };
//^ index = index of T* inside "globalManagerList"       
std::vector<Manager*> globalManagerList;
std::vector<std::function<Manager*(int)>>* getFunctionPointers(){
    static std::vector<std::function<Manager*(int)>> cacher;
    return &cacher;
}
/** it is called indirectly by "requestSystem" */
template<class T> int indirectCall(){
    std::function<Manager*(int)> func=[](int assignIndex){
        IndexCache<T>::index = assignIndex;
        auto re= new T();   
        globalManagerList.push_back(re);
        return re;
    };
    getFunctionPointers()->push_back(func);
    int dummy=42;return dummy;
}
template<class T> T* requestSystem(){
    int k=DummyHook<T>::dummyInt; 
        //^ optimized out, but force calling "indirectCall()" before main() at @
    return static_cast<T*>(globalManagerList[IndexCache<T>::index]);
}
template<class T> int DummyHook<T>::dummyInt = indirectCall<T>(); //@
template<class T> int IndexCache<T>::index = -42;
```

Here is the main function :-

```
int main() {
    auto fs=getFunctionPointers();
    int n=0;
    for(auto ele: *fs){
        ele(n); ++n;
        //^ call every function in 
        //  static std::vector<std::function<Manager*(int)>> cacher
    }
    std::cout<<"All initialized, ready!"<<std::endl;
    auto entityManagerPtr=requestSystem<EntityManager>();
    auto advanceManagerPtr=requestSystem<AdvanceEntityManager>();
    //^ In this program, they are different instance, but I want it to be the same instance.
    std::cout<<"Should be 5 : "<<advanceManagerPtr->testField<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output (both managers are instantiated `:(`):-

```
Manager
EntityManager
Manager
EntityManager
AdvanceEntityManager
All initialized, ready!
Should be 5 : 5
```

Comment: You are trying to pass `C`, which is a type name, to `f`, which is a function. Functions take instances of types, not types. Why not call `is_base_of` directly where you need it?

Comment: @Joseph Thomson  Because I want to cache a lot of `std::function` into a list (`std::vector`).  `f` is one of them.

Comment: What are you doing with the list? What you are trying to do is impossible. There may be other ways to achieve what you want though.

Comment: I can manipulate type information in this way.  It is useful to initialize something complex (in a hacky way).   For example, `std::vector= {A::initialize(),B::initialize(),...}`,  or `{[](){return new A();},[](){return new B();},...}` and other black magic around types.   I rarely use it, but it is very handy in such rare situation.

Comment: @java those are operations on values not types.  If you want a type system that is reflectable at runtime, you have to write it in C++; RTTI is limited in C++ for a number of reasons, including efficiency and optimization.  There are compile time reflection proposals that could make runtime reflection easier to implement, but they are not in C++ at this point.  Please describe the underlying problem you wish to solve so it can be solved, and not just one solution you cannot figure out.

Comment: @Yakk    As far as I know, I can cache everything about type by using `std::function` if I try *hard enough*.   But now, I am stunned that there is an exception - I can't cache a function checking `is_base_of` because it is a template function.  ..... Then, I just hope that C++ will have some magically way to workaround it. ......  If there is none, I guess I should do something more of a "good practice".    (I understand, I can't pass type.).   :]

Comment: @Yakk  I try to add underlying problem.  It is just the first-tier-underlying, but I hope it can clarify thing a little better.  :)

Comment: you can't. you basically try to implement Java's `instanceof` which is not possible without `dynamic_cast`

Comment: `std::is_base_of` is **not** a (template) function. It's a **template**.

Comment: @Daniel Jour Thank for fixing my misunderstanding!

Comment: That table is easy for fixed types.  For non fixed types, it is just a restating of your problem.  As mentioned you can write your own type system to do that at runtime if you reaoky need it.  I suppose you have a reason to want that table to be printed, but you continue to avoid stating what it is.  I do not want a rephrasing of the exact same problem, **but what useful thing in an actual product you are hoping to do with it**.  If you just want to build a graph like that, using C++ types seems a strange way to do it.

Comment: To distinguish a restating from an underlying problem, imagine you had your "underlying problem" solved.  Would it be easy to solve the problem you are using to solve it?  If so, **they are the same problem restated**.  They are equivalent.  If A reduces to B and B reduces to A, then they are one problem up to the cost of reduction.  Can you imagine a limitation on your table generation such that it would not be easy to produce the std function you ask from the table?  If so, focus on *that*, because that is where there is traction.

Comment: @Yakk  Thank a lot for dedicating your precious time to describe.  I totally missed your point.  I have just added the 2nd underlying problem.

Comment: Nice.  Ok, next question: is there a spot where all of the types involved could be listed?  Even a place where you could type `template<class...>struct types_t{};` and do a `using all_supported_types = types_t<S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6>;`?  It doesn't even have to be in a public header.

Comment: @Yakk   Thank.  XD .....  No.  That is the hard part.   ..... By the way, I am creating a MCVE, will finish within 15-30 minutes.

Comment: @Yakk  I have add MCVE.  It is really close to my real case.  XD

Answer (score 1):

The list of bases of a type is not avaliable at runtime, which is what your code in effect requires.

We can however write our own typesystem.  In this case, we mark up each type with a list of each parent, and enable compile time reflection over that list.

Then when we set up the factories, we also replace the factories for the parent types, and ensure that only the child type is used.

Here is some random tools to help:

```
template<class...Ts> struct types_t {};
template<class T> struct tag_t { constexpr tag_t() {} using type=T; };
template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
template<class Tag> using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    return [](auto&& f)->decltype(auto) {
        return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
    };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ={} ) {
    return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<class F>
auto invoke_foreach( F&& f ) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args){
        using discard=int[];
        (void)discard{0,(void(
            f(decltype(args)(args))
        ),0)...};
    };
}
template<class F>
auto invoke_on_tuple( F&& f ) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& tuple)->decltype(auto) {
        using Tuple = decltype(tuple);
        using dTuple = std::decay_t<Tuple>;
        using Size = std::tuple_size<dTuple>;
        return index_upto<Size{}>()( [&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
            return f( std::get<decltype(args){}>( decltype(tuple)(tuple) )... );
        });
    };
}
template<class...Ts>
constexpr std::tuple< tag_t<Ts>... > as_tuple_tags( types_t<Ts...> ) { return std::make_tuple(tag<Ts>...); }

template<class F>
struct y_combinator_t {
    F f;
    template<class...Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()( Args&&... args ) {
        return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
template<class F>
y_combinator_t<std::decay_t<F>> y_combinate( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

Now, we mark up types with their parents:

```
class Manager{
    public: Manager(){std::cout<<"Manager"<<std::endl; }
};
class EntityManager : public Manager{
    public:
        int base_value = 3;
        EntityManager(){std::cout<<"EntityManager"<<std::endl;}
        using parents = types_t<Manager>;
};
class AdvanceEntityManager : public EntityManager{
    public: int testField=5; //just for testing
    public:
    AdvanceEntityManager(){
      std::cout<<"AdvanceEntityManager"<<std::endl;
      base_value = 1;
    }
    using parents = types_t<EntityManager>;
};
```

and use the starting code to let us easily work with parents:

```
template<class T, class Parents = typename T::parents>
auto foreach_parent( tag_t<T> ) {
    constexpr auto parent_tuple = as_tuple_tags( Parents() );
    return [](auto&& f) {
        return invoke_on_tuple(invoke_foreach(f))(decltype(parent_tuple){});
    };
}

template<class T, class...Ts>
auto foreach_parent( tag_t<T>, Ts&&... ) {
    return [](auto&& f) {};
}
```

we set up a two-entry cache, a singleton factory, and use smart pointers:

```
template<class T> class IndexCache{
public:
    static int index;
    static int factory;
};
template<class T> class Dummy{ public: static int index; };

using pManager = std::shared_ptr<Manager>;
using ManagerFactory = std::function<pManager()>;
using Task = std::function<void()>;

std::vector<pManager> globalManagerList;
std::vector<Task>& getManagerFactories(){
    static std::vector<Task> cacher{};
    return cacher;
}

template<class T>
ManagerFactory singleton_factory() {
    return []{
        static auto single = (void(std::cout << "making " << typeid(T).name() << " singlton" << std::endl), std::make_shared<T>());
        return single;
    };
}
```

and modify indirect call to replace the parent factory tasks:

```
template<class T>
void indirectCall(){
    std::cout << "Setting up " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    auto func=[](auto tag){
        return [tag](){
            IndexCache<type_t<decltype(tag)>>::index = globalManagerList.size();
            globalManagerList.push_back(singleton_factory<T>()());
        };
    };
    //std::cout << "Adding " << typeid(T).name() << " factory " << std::endl;
    IndexCache<T>::factory = getManagerFactories().size();
    getManagerFactories().push_back(func(tag<T>));
    auto replace_parents = y_combinate(
      [&](auto& replace_parents, auto child_tag) {
        foreach_parent(child_tag)([&](auto parent_tag){
          using Parent = type_t<decltype(parent_tag)>;
          std::cout << "Replacing " << typeid(Parent).name() << " factory with " << typeid(T).name() << " factory" << std::endl;
          getManagerFactories()[IndexCache<Parent>::factory] = func(tag<Parent>);
          replace_parents( parent_tag );
        });
      }
    );
    replace_parents(tag<T>);
    std::cout << "Added " << typeid(T).name() << " factory " << std::endl;
}
```

In `requestSystem`, we ensure that all of the setup has been done:

```
void setup_code() {
    for (auto&& factory:getManagerFactories())
        factory();
}
void setup() {
    static int unused = (setup_code(),7);
    (void)unused;
}
template<class T>
T* requestSystem()
{
    int dummy = Dummy<T>::index;
    (void)dummy;
    std::cout << "Requesting " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    setup();
    return static_cast<T*>(globalManagerList[IndexCache<T>::index].get());
}

template<class T> int IndexCache<T>::index = -1;
template<class T> int IndexCache<T>::factory = -1;
template<class T> int Dummy<T>::index = (indirectCall<T>(), 7);
```

and then we test it:

```
int main() {
    std::cout<<"All initialized, ready!"<<std::endl;
    auto entityManagerPtr=requestSystem<EntityManager>();
    //std::cout<<"Phase 1"<<std::endl;
    (void)entityManagerPtr;
    auto advanceManagerPtr=requestSystem<AdvanceEntityManager>();
    //std::cout<<"Phase 2"<<std::endl;
    //^ In this program, they are different instance, but I want it to be the same instance.
    std::cout<<"Should be 5 : "<<advanceManagerPtr->testField<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Should be 1 : "<<entityManagerPtr->base_value<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

here we ask for the `entityManagerPtr`, and we get the `advanceManagerPtr`.  We can see from the logs that only one object was created, and its entityManagerPtr->base_value was 1.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f25638bf034263b).